# Count the number of positive integer $n \leq 2019$ such that $11n+20$ relatively prime with $3+5n$

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Here is my approach.

Since
$$11n+20 = 2(3+5n) + (n+14)$$
then
$$1=(11n+20,3+5n)=(3+5n,n+14)$$

I don't how to continue, because for some $n$, $3+5n > n+14$. And for other $n$, $3+5n \leq n+14$.

Any advice?

Comment: You could do a case division, in fact there are only three integers $\{0,1,2\}$ for which $n+14\geq 3+5n$

Comment: $\gcd$ and Euclid's algorithm doesn't really care about smaller or larger, positive or negative. The only reason we say they do is to make sure that the algorithm stops at some point. Just keep moving forward.

Comment: This question arises the new question: Count the number of positive integers $n \leq M$ such that $an+b$ relatively prime with $cn+d$

Comment: Ok, Arthur. It is a new information for me. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah. It is a general form of my question, SARTHAK GUPTA.

Comment: Ok, b00n heT. Thanks. But, i think it will be faster if i did as Arthur said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close. $(5n+3,n+14)=(-67,n+14)$

So I am counting the number of positive integers such that $67\nmid n+14$. There are 30 numbers that fail so there are 1989 numbers that work.

Comment: Yeah. I get it. We should exclude the multiple of 67.